# Почему код всегда возвращает true?

Tags: java, scanner

Пользователь должен ввести с консоли букву "а", чтобы высветилось "Вы ввели правильный символ, спасибо". В обратном случае уведомление должно быть таким: "Ошибка! Вы ввели неверный символ". Но даже при неправильных символах всегда высвечивается "Вы ввели правильный символ, спасибо".

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class StreamReader {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Введите а");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println(s);
        String input = "a";
        boolean foo = Pattern.matches("a",input);
        if(foo){
            System.out.println("Вы ввели правильный символ, спасибо");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Ошибка! Вы ввели неверный символ");
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите внимательней.

```
String s = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println(s);
String input = "a";
boolean foo = Pattern.matches("a",input);
```

Строка пользователя считалась в переменную `s`. А вы сравниваете строку `"a"` и переменную `input`. Естественно, `foo` всегда будет `true`.

Именно поэтому переменные и методы должны называться нормально, а не абстрактными `s`, `a`, `123` и т.д. Если бы вы `s` переименовали в `actualStr`, а `input` в `expectedStr`, скорее всего никакой ошибки бы не было.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, я поменял название переменных но  ответ все равно всегда true(( подскажите может другой способ решения этой задачи, я просто не смог найти в интернете метод которым можно задавать определенное значение пользователю что бы выполялось то или иное действие в зависимости от ввода

Comment: @SatanIsLoki поменять название переменных - просто моя рекомендация, которая никак не влияет на работоспособность кода. А вы лишнюю переменную удалили? Способ решения этой задачи обычный, такой же как у вас, только вы, видимо, ошибку не исправили.

Comment: уже удалил, спасибо) я просто думал что нельзя ту же перемунную использывать под scan.nextLine(); Возможно у вас есть какие-то контакты или я могу скинуть свои для дальнейшего общения, если вы не против, спасибо ещё раз за помощь

Comment: @SatanIsLoki задавайте свои вопросы на этом сайте. Вам ответят